# Broken Exhaust Manifold Stud - How to remove?

Tags: malibu, stuck-bolt, exhaust-manifold

I was changing the Exhaust Manifold on an '09 Chevy Malibu. When tightening the bolt with the new one on, I twisted the whole bolt and stud off. So I have a couple issues. The broken stud is now left on the back of my engine.

What should I do to fix this? 
Options considered:
Remove the broken stud. If so how? Weld a nut, drill it out, etc. 
Leave it? There are 9 other bolts. Is that good enough to form a seal with 1 missing? Currently, it still leaks exhaust.

Another question here: [Question2](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/33587/broken-exhaust-manifold-stud-replacement-part-specs-or-part-number).

Comment: Picture of broken stud would be nice, ever situation is different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely try to extract it.

**Preparation:**

- Heat the manifold with a blowtorch
- Jolt the bolt with a pin punch
- Soak the bolt with bp-blaster or another penetrating oil

**Removal**

- If the bolt is protruding: Place two nuts on it, counter them against each other and try to screw the bolt out.
- If the bolt is protruding but not enough for the two nuts: Grind a small groove in the bolt, use a punch to hammer tangentially into the groove thereby causing the bolt to rotate counterclockwise.
- Drill the bolt out. If you damage the threads: Drill the hole larger and use a "time-sert" or "ensat" thread insert.
- This solution also exists, but it is dangerous: Drill a hole into the bolt. Then hammer a torx bit into it and try to remove the bolt. Attention: If the bit breaks your bolt is filled with a hardened steel inlay, not allowing a second chance.
- The best method: Buy a screw extractor set, including a left cutting drill bit

**Installing the manifold**

To prevent other seized bolts: Be sure to use some anti-seize (cooper or ceramic paste) on the bolts. Attention: The recommended torque is for a dry bolt unless the instructions tell you to lubricate the parts.

Comment: Small correction. The recommended torque is for a dry bolt unless the instructions tell you to lubricate the parts.

Comment: I posted what actually worked in my situation below, but I'm giving you the answer, since I think it will be more useful to others coming here in the future.

Comment: I'll also add. Use a torque wrench when reinstalling the manifold. The bolts  are a beast to remove, but require a surprisingly low amount of torque to spec. If you don't have a torque wrench, make them snug, but don't put all your strength into it.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research, I decided to start by trying a pair of vice-grips on what was left of the stud. I cranked them down real tight, and it came right out.

If that didn't work I'd have been going down the route of drilling, welding, or other more terrible options.