# Broken Exhaust Manifold Stud - Replacement part specs or part number

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, stuck-bolt, exhaust-manifold

I was changing the Exhaust Manifold on an '09 Chevy Malibu. When tightening the bolt with the new one on, I twisted the whole bolt and stud off. So I have a couple issues. The broken stud is now left on the back of my engine.

Assuming I can remove the broken stud, I can't find online the specs or part number for a replacement. Does anyone know the specs/part # or where I can look it up.

Another question here: [Question2](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/33585/broken-exhaust-manifold-stud-how-to-remove) .

Edit: Called the dealer. OEM part number:11589054. Full specs: m8x1.25x20, m8x1.25x16, gm 6175m, 10.9, gm 7111m hdr. So now I can search for OEM parts. Dorman 03411 look close? Any idea if these would work?

Comment: Which engine? Plus, what is the size of the nut which goes on the stud? I can probably reverse engineer it if you give me the wrench size which goes on the nut.

Comment: You are best top buy a new bolt from the GM Dealership

Comment: It's the 4 cylinder. And it uses a 13mm wrench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dlu for the first tip. From the dealer specs I was able to locate the following:

Dorman - Autograde 29323 Double Ended Stud - M8-1.25 x 18mm and M8-1.25 x 17mm
[https://www.amazon.com/Dorman-Autograde-29323-Double-M8-1-25/dp/B000DCO42U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000DCO42U)

I bought a pack of 2 at Advance for like $5 and they worked perfectly. Only difference is you'll have to screw the two nuts on to install the stud. If you don't have the fancy hex bit on the OEM ends you'd be going this route anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to, or call, a dealer they should be able to tell you (or sell you) what you need. If you luck is good you may be able to find the information by looking at a parts diagram if you can find one.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty repair you can just use a threaded rod with the same thread size/pitch and cut it to size. You could also use a matching bolt and cut the head off (use a high grade bolt). Attention: automotive engineers love to use some unusual thread size/pitch, perhaps you want to measure the thread with a matching gauge.
Do not forget the anti-seize when installing the new stud.

Comment: I would not trust generic threaded rod to match the strength spec of the original bolt unless it was marked as such